# Setting the aspectRatio to true for the corner resize handles

Tags: jquery-ui

When I drag something from a corner handle, and the diagonal two-headed arrow appears, I kind of expect that the aspect ratio of my object is going to be locked in while I drag, but this isn't the case. You can move the mouse left or right, or up or down, while resizing from a corner handle (and the diagonal arrow is displayed) and change only the width or the height of your object. That's not an intuitive behavior and it's annoying when it destroys the aspect ratio that you may have been trying to preserve, say of an image.  Is there any way to have the corner handles preserve the aspect ratio,  while the n, s, w, and e handles still allow just the width or just the height to be changed?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to work this out?

Comment: I'd like to know this as well...